# Need to add Subgroups members into Parent Group

Tags: javascript, groovy, boomi

I'm creating a scenario where I need to include the Subgroup UIDs in the Parent group.
Parent groups with members (UIDs) and some parent groups with members (UIDs) and subgroup names can be found in the inbound file that I'm extracting. Members of the subgroups (UIDs) are arriving individually.
The requirement is that I add the UIDs of the members of the subgroup to the parent group, which already has the name of the subgroup.

Please help me to implement Javascript or Groovy script to get this conclusion.

Kindly see the below mentioned example for inbound file:

{
"cn":[
"LEG-onit_le-business"
],
"member" :[
"cn=LEGG-onit-auto_function-hr,ou=Groups,o=world",
"cn=LEGG-onit-test_le-business-manual,ou=Groups,o=world",
"uid=DDO357,ou=people,ou=pg,o=world"
],
}

{
"cn":[
"LEGG-onit-auto_function"
],
"member" :[
"uid=AP1460,ou=people,ou=pg,o=world",
"uid=CT0306,ou=people,ou=pg,o=world"
],
}

{
"cn":[
"LEGG-onit-test_le-business-manual"
],
"member" :[
"uid=EE3051,ou=people,ou=pg,o=world",
"uid=tt4386,ou=people,ou=pg,o=world"
],
}

Note: LEG - indicates Parent Group
LEGG - indicates Subgroup

Comment: Can you elaborate on what members, parent groups, and sub-groups are, and describe how they relate to the 3 JSON structures you show?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The way your data is declared is pretty sub-optimal, with information like which item is a parent group or sub-group encoded in a String (the CN field) which makes this task harder than it should. The first thing to do is transform the data so that this information becomes obvious (parse the CN, extract the CN fields into actual fields in the parsed objects)... from there, it's a pretty basic programming task... once you've done that, if you still can't complete the task, you can at least ask a more specific question than just "solve this problem".